# What to do here?

Tags: tournament

Im in this situation sometimes and I'm always as insecure of what to do here.

When this hand goes into a 3-bet, 4-bet and then they shove.

Ofcourse it depends on table structure and what not but if we only look at this situation as it present to us as in the picture i attatched here.

Is this mostly a call if someone shoves us if we have pocket kings on the flop if it turnes out rainbow like this situation.

Im always scared about sets/two-pairs and aces. This situation doesn't happen A LOT, but when it does, i don't really know what to do.
Do you call?

/Iggy[image]

Comment: great question, could you possibly provide us with more information? For example were you heads up on the flop? what were the stack sizes? What was the action preflop and on the flop so far?

Comment: What Clarko said. It would be especially helpful to know which players or how many players are still in the hand.

Comment: Playing with decent players, it's almost always a set or some 45s that may have called preflop depending on the situation. Against maniacs, well, they could be stacking themselves off with something like A9, so call

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a general question of facing aggression postflop with a strong hand, so some thoughts on that.

1. If there's substantial PRF action, like you called a 4bet or someone called your 3bet, going with KK is probably mandatory on this board. There many value hands that will be weaker than KK.
2. If its a open/call PRF, i think that player tendency starts to play a big part of how i'd navigate. Against normal players im getting it in, against nits i may start to think of checking down/folding. Im much more inclined to fold on a dry board than a wet board, since there arent that many bluffs on a 932 rainbow board.
3. If your stacksize is <2-3x the pot, i think its going to be hard to get away.
4. Either way, I find that these spots tend to be high variance, esp if you intend to call down a check-raise 3barrel. Even if you played correctly, be prepared to lose big pots sometimes.